# Translate a texture in Cycles Material node editor?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

Essentially I just want to translate a checker texture to the side a little bit.

[image]

Is there a way to do this in a cycles material?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you must provide texture coordinates to the texture node, something like *Object* or *Generated* should do.

Then you can use a *Vector Mapping* node to add or subtract values.

Comment: Node name is *Vector Mapping* not *Vector Math*, my mistake, fixed now.

Comment: Vector Math works ok for translations, and MixRGB also; just set the operation to 'ADD' and use the second input as the translation vector.

Comment: Yes they probably do, good thing cycles is such a well though out and flexible render engine with an incredibly modular and ingenious node system